# unable to load url in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to load one url "http://connect.mayoclinic.org/discussions" in webview .i tried lots of ways but i am unable to load it.its showing blank page. I am using the following for this.when i use simple load url by removing other functions,then also its giving the blank page.but when i tested on webbrowser its showing the webpage. its showing on iphone also..only unable to show in android webview

```
this.wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);


WebSettings settings = wb.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BrowserViewHealthAlertActivity.this).create();

progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(BrowserViewHealthAlertActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
progressBar.setCancelable(true);
progressBar.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        CommonFunction.startTimer(context);
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            return true; // Pretend we processed it
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && (event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) == KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) {
            return true;
        }
        return false; // Any other keys are still
    }
});

wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        CommonFunction.startTimer(context);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage(description);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
wb.loadUrl(link);
```

Comment: just replace this url https://www.google.com/ then test app because url is wrong

Comment: url is right..u can check on browser

Comment: Try wb.loadUrl(url);

Comment: yes..i had tried...its not working

Comment: Do you have internet permissions in manifest?

Comment: yes...i had..its very big project...its showing lots of urls..but this one is not

Comment: Think you have to remove the loadUrl in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, and return false.

Comment: i tried..its not working

Answer (score 0):

A simple Webview goes here displaying loading until URL take to load.

```
Webview webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        // Log.e("in", "onPageStarted" + isInternetPresent);
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            // Log.e("in", "if" + isInternetPresent);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noconnection.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            retry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else
            noconnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        // Log.e("in", "onloadresoure");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.setInitialScale(1);

if (isInternetPresent) {
    isInternetPresent = true;
    webview.loadUrl("http://your url");
} else {
    ExitAlertClass.QuizSelectOptionAlert(ctx, "No Internet Connection"); //here goes your alert code
          noconnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
};
```

progressBar is a simple progress:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

Here, I am getting status of internet usng broadcast receiver. You can make that code.

Comment: can you have any other soln

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your URL. Its not woring in browser.
might be problem with the URL itself @asiya.
Is it giving black page still??

Check my code with another URL like www.google.com. Its my working code.

Comment: yes...my code is also working for other urls...its only not working for http://connect.mayoclinic.org/discussions

Comment: its still giving blank page

Comment: then it's problem in url asiya.. No chance for it i think so

Comment: I will get you if i found any solution for like these URLS